# Google Cloud Dataproc migration to Spark 1.6.0

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

Will Google Dataproc start using Spark 1.6.0 anytime soon ? I'm creating a cluster using this command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create <cluster-name>
```

and it defaults to using Spark 1.5.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expect to see a new image version for Google Cloud Dataproc which contains Spark 1.6.x within the coming weeks.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/dataproc-versions lists the available versions. Currently you have a choice of Spark 1.5.0 or Spark 1.5.2 (the default).